Constructing a non-similar right triangle from the altitude and half-hypotenuse of a right triangle

Inside right triangle with side lengths $(a,b,c)$ and angles $(A,B,90^\circ)$,
we can construct a (usually) non-similar right-triangle with side lengths $\left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{2c}, \frac{2ab}{2c},  \frac{a^2+b^2}{2c}\right)$ and angles $(90-2A^\circ, 2A, 90^\circ)$.
(The altitude of the original triangle equals a leg of the new triangle, and the new hypotenuse is half of the old hypotenuse.)
This construction can be iterated indefinitely (switching the order of the legs when necessary).
If a,b,c are rational, then all the side lengths in the sequence are rational, generating Pythagorean triples based on the standard formula.
If A,B are rational multiples of turn, then the iteration is periodic.
The $(30^\circ, 60^\circ, 90^\circ)$ aka $(1,\sqrt3,2)$ triangle is a non-stable fixed point of the iteration.
What is this phenomenon called? Where can I read more about it?

Up to similar  triangles, you have the iteration $z:=a+bi$ goes to $z^2=(a^2-b^2)+(2ab)i$. Thus, this is just the iteration $z\mapsto z^2$.

Ah, so, taking the hypotenuse as a complex number (vector) where the legs are aligned to the real and imaginary axes, and squaring it (doubling its angle), we get the vector corresponding (in the same way deacobed above) to that internal triangle.  This is compatible with the observation that a 30-60-90 triangle's internal triangle is similar, since the square of 30° vector is a 60° vector, which is a 30° vector from the other axis.  And that's is also compatible with the observation that rational angles (compled roots of unity) are (eventually) periodic under this mapping.

Also compatible with rational side lengths mapping to rational side lengths, but that was already clear from the construction.  Remaining questions would be: is there more to say about the connection between $z \leftarrow z^2$ and the "circles and translation" geometric construction? I've seen some mentions made of group-theoretical structure of sets of Pythagorean triples. Is this related? (link to paper)
